# Does a python virtual environment avoid redundant installs?

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python and I'm beginning to work with python virtual environments. When I create a virtual environment, I have to reinstall all the modules that I need for the current project that I'm working on. 
I'm wondering if the virtual environment somehow avoids redundancies in installation of modules if the same version of the module had already been installed in another project or on a system-wide level?

Also, would there be any point in installing modules on a system-wide level rather than just in virtual environments, since I would need to install the modules in the virtual environment anyway?

Comment: Rather the opposite! Each virtualenv will install all the modules and there is no sharing with other virtualenvs. But then, this is exactly the point of virtualenv - No sharing of modules thus allowing independent dependency changes.

Comment: not exactly your question, but related, pip will cache built wheels (like installs) of your packages such that each install is speedier

Comment: I think this is a good question and most of the answers avoid addressing what it's actually asking; which is whether or not Python keeps two copies of the same *version* of a dependency across multiple virtual environments. The question is asking whether Python is smart enough to only keep two copies of the same dependency if they are different versions, and the answer is that it isn't. The answers imply this is a merit of the design, but I think this is actually not ideal, which is why this question was asked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Short Answer :**

If you work with virtual environment, you need to install every dependecy (package) that you need for your project even if you installed this package in another virtual environment before.

That's exactly the purpose of virtual environment : each project has its own dependencies. That allows you to manage the dependencies clearly for each project without affecting others.

Of course **you can** install a dependecy (a package) globally by doing

`pip install <Package name>`

*But before doing that be sure to not activate any virtual environment .* This will install the package at the root installation of python which is the main environment.

But **it is strongly not recommended** to do that and working with virtual environment is always a good practice.

**Extras :**

Now just in addition to this answer you can use the command :

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

This will create a file call `requirements.txt` in your project's root folder.

This file looks like this :

```
numpy==1.18.1
pandas==0.25.3
```

In this example i installed in my virtual environment the package `numpy` version 1.18.1 and the package `pandas` in its version 0.25.3

In this way, if another project needs the package numpy in a *newer* or *older* version, i can manage this directly in its `requirements.txt` without affecting other projects .

This file will also help you to re-install quickly and easily your dependencies of your environment (for example if you want to create another project with the same starting dependencies as your current project) by just doing :

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

*Of course : be sure to first copy this requirements.txt file to your target's root folder of the new project and activate its virtual environment before doing that*

**Quick summary in commands :**

1) Install virtual env (Linux):

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

Install virtual env (Windows):

```
pip install virtualenv
```

2) Create a new virtual environment (linux and Windows ) :

```
 virtualenv  venv
```

Be sure to do `cd` to your root project folder before doing that. This will create a new folder called "venv" (or whatever name you put after the virtualenv command but venv is a convention and a goo practice). If you are not in your root folder and for any reason you do not want to, you always can add a `-p` flag to this command inn order to precise the path you want to install your virtual environment like so :

```
virtualenv -p /YOUR_PROJECT_PATH/ venv
```

3) activate the virtual environment (Linux) :

```
$ source  YOUR_PROJECT_PATH/venv/bin/activate
```

If you call your virtual environment differently than venv be sure to replace venv by whatever you did call.

activate the virtual environment (Windows) :

```
C:\> YOUR_PROJECT_PATH\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

After this you should have this prompt :

Linux :

```
(venv) $
```

Windows :

```
(venv) C:\>
```

4) Install a package  :

Linux    `(venv) $ pip3 install <package_name>`

Windows    `(venv) C:\> pip install <package_name>`

This command will install the `<package_name>` only in the venv site-packages folder and this dependency will only be available for this virtual environment.

5) Freeze your dependencies   :

Linux    `(venv) $ pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Windows        `(venv) C:\> pip freeze > requirements.txt`

This as said above will create the `requirements.txt` in your project root folder (it will contains a list of all your packages name and their versions you installed in this virtual environment)

6) deactivate you virtual environment :

```
deactivate
```

If you create a new environment by doing the above step and you want this  new environment to have the same dependencies as the first one :

```
cp YOUR_FIRST_PROJECT_PATH\requirements.txt YOUR_NEW_PROJECT_PATH
cd YOUR_NEW_PROJECT_PATH
```

Here Create and activate your new virtual environment (as explained above) then :

```
pip install requirements.txt
```

7) Install a package globally **(not recommended)** :
    if you have a current activated venv first :

```
deactivate
```

Then :

```
pip install <package_name>
```

This will install the package_name at the root installation of python.

For further comprehension of course :

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score 0):

Virtual environments segregate modules for an application. This means that upgrading modules in one application does not impact another application. Since modules occasionally have breaking changes, this can be important.

Are you using the requirements.txt file to help manage the dependencies? It makes installing them easier when you need to reset a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not but that is the main point of having virtual environments because libraries depend on another and thus upgrading or modifying a library in one environment does not affect other environments.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual environments are semi-isolated Python environments (self-contained directory) that allows packages to be installed for use by a particular application, rather that being installed system wide.

The main advantage being that it enables the user to install for each python project/environment  different libraries, dependencies and why not, even a different Python interpreter.

Please take a look here: https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/ it will explain more thoroughly