# Run TheHarvester tool on a windows machine : python module not found

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm running TheHarvester tool on Windows 10.
How to resolve this error?

`C:\Users\xxx\Desktop`

> theharvester
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "E:\PentestBox\bin\InformationGathering\theHarvester\theHarvester.py", line 6, in 
>       import asyncio
>   ImportError: No module named asyncio

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z29Wz.png]

[image]

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Please actually show the code that produced the error.

Answer (score 2):

***SHORT ANSWER***

This package (theHarevest.py) has a dependecy (uvloop.py) that is not supported on windows
(related issue : https://github.com/MagicStack/uvloop/issues/14)

Two solutions to get it run :

1)  **Virtual machine** (using VirtualBox with a Linux image for example)

2)  **Docker for windows** (I personaly prefer this solution because it is by far more easy to run and consume less resources even if it runs its own linux virtual machine under the hood) :

Here is one image of theHarvester that seems to be really simple to run : https://hub.docker.com/r/beardyjay/theharvester/

You just have to install Docker on windows and run this image as explained in this link

***EXTRA 1***

Now just by the way (not really related to the windows support problem) : you installed the asyncio package in your C:\ driver. (You did `pip install asyncio` on C:).
But you tried to run theHarvester.py on your E:\ driver....

If you have Python also installed on E: just do `E:` on your command prompt to switch to E and then do `pip install asyncio` there.

But the better practice would be to work with the same python installation on your machine so you could do :

`C:\<YOUR_PATH_TO_PYTHON.EXE> E:\PentestBox\bin\InformationGathering\theHarvester\theHarvester.py`

(this assuming that E:\ belongs to the same machine and ***is not*** a mapping to another machine)

Of course, because the Harvester not supported yet on windows, those installation won't be usefull....but this was just to explain the import problem

***EXTRA 2***:

As i mentioned here 
[Does a python virtual environment avoid redundant installs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61564609/does-a-python-virtual-environment-avoid-redundant-installs/61564762#61564762)

it is also a better practice to work with virtual environments. You 
should check this out too...

Comment: I'm using Python in C: |...........
E: \ and C: \ on the same machine.
I unzipped Winpython in E: \ driver
And now? What do I do?
I added a new photo to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Now you should be able to run the theHarvester.py without the import problem...try an let us know if it's okay

Comment: It doesn't run. I added a new photo2 to the question

Comment: As you noticed : theHarvester.py has a dependecy (uvloop) that is not supported on windows for the moment...please see here for more information https://github.com/MagicStack/uvloop/issues/14